# Add image to AR Resources on the fly for image recognition

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

`ARKit` 1.5 introduces image recognition. In the code you have to create a Set of the reference images like this:

```
let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil)
```

and then images contained in the Set can be recognised.

I wanted to know if it is possible to add images on the fly to this `AR Resources` folder. For example a user could take a picture and send it to a server, it is then recognised by the `ARKit`. Or a user could receive a set of images based on his location, etc.

Comment: Probably "On-Demand Resources"?
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/
Or add each image programmatically: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2942252-init

Comment: thank you, I will look at it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot amend the contents of the default folder at runtime, although you can create images on the fly.

[image]

As an example let's put an image into the `Assets Folder` (not the ARResources one), which in my case is called 'moonTarget'.

We could then create a function which we call in `viewDidLoad` etc:

```
/// Create ARReference Images From Somewhere Other Than The Default Folder
func loadDynamicImageReferences(){

    //1. Get The Image From The Folder
    guard let imageFromBundle = UIImage(named: "moonTarget"),
    //2. Convert It To A CIImage
    let imageToCIImage = CIImage(image: imageFromBundle),
    //3. Then Convert The CIImage To A CGImage
    let cgImage = convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: imageToCIImage)else { return }

    //4. Create An ARReference Image (Remembering Physical Width Is In Metres)
    let arImage = ARReferenceImage(cgImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up, physicalWidth: 0.2)

    //5. Name The Image
    arImage.name = "CGImage Test"

    //5. Set The ARWorldTrackingConfiguration Detection Images
    configuration.detectionImages = [arImage]
}


/// Converts A CIImage To A CGImage
///
/// - Parameter inputImage: CIImage
/// - Returns: CGImage
func convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent) {
     return cgImage
    }
    return nil
}
```

We can then test this in the `ARSCNViewDelegate`:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    let x = currentImageAnchor.transform
    print(x.columns.3.x, x.columns.3.y , x.columns.3.z)

    //2. Get The Targets Name
    let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

    //3. Get The Targets Width & Height In Meters
    let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
    let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

    print("""
    Image Name = \(name)
    Image Width = \(width)
    Image Height = \(height)
    """)

    //4. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    planeNode.opacity = 0.25
    planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

    //5. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

    //The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    //6. Create AN SCNBox
    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

    //7. Create A Different Colour For Each Face
    let faceColours = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.gray]
    var faceMaterials = [SCNMaterial]()

    //8. Apply It To Each Face
    for face in 0 ..< 5{
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = faceColours[face]
        faceMaterials.append(material)
    }
    boxGeometry.materials = faceMaterials
    boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry

    //9. Set The Boxes Position To Be Placed On The Plane (node.x + box.height)
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0 , 0.05, 0)

    //10. Add The Box To The Node
    node.addChildNode(boxNode)   
}
```

As you can see the same could also be applied from a live feed as well.

Hope this helps...

As @Karlis said you could also look at using `OnDemandResouces` and then converting them to desired specs of an `ARReferenceImage`.

**Update:** For anyone looking to see an example of creating dynamic reference images from a Server please take a look at the following project I have created: [Dynamic Reference Images Sample Code](https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARKitDynamicReferenceImages)

Comment: Many thanks! So here when you set `configuration.detectionImages = [arImage]` the detectable images are limited to the one you just created right? Or does it add up to the ones already present in the AR Resource folder? I think I need to access the configuration of the current session, then access the actual set of images, then add my new image to this set, sounds correct?

Comment: From my testing if you need to use the ARBundle you need to use: ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: AR_BUNDLE, bundle: nil), then if you want to use dynamic ones you will need to create a new set. You can alternate between them though :)

Comment: I don't get why @op didn't accept this answer. anyways, thank you! it solved my problem :)

Comment: Hi @BlackMirrorz!! Would you have time to help me with ARkit related question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927167/swift-get-the-truthdepth-camera-parameters-for-face-tracking-in-arkit :(

Answer (score 5):

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let pathToObject = documentDirectory + "/reference.jpg"
let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToObject)
let imageData: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
let cgImage = image!.cgImage

let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.init(cgImage!, orientation: .up, physicalWidth: 0.595)
referenceImages.name = "Reference Image"
let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.trackingImages = [referenceImages]
session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```